# Issues with my regex to validate sub-domain?

Tags: javascript, regex

greetings all
I need the sub-domains to be something like:

```
sub1 (letters or digits)
sub1-sub (letters or digits-letters or digits)
```

so I am using the following JavaScript regex, but it always return false
i don't know why, please advise.

```
var reg  = /^[A-Z0-9]?[-A-Z0-9]$/i;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're forgetting a *?

```
var reg  = /^[A-Z0-9]?[-A-Z0-9]*$/i;
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to match? The regex I gave would indeed match the two subdomains you gave as an example, so you must be giving it different input. Are you giving it the whole domain?

Comment: Note that this also allows an empty string as well as strings that do not start or end with a alphanumeric character (e.g. `-`, `foo-`, `-bar`) and strings that contain more than one consecutive hyphens (e.g. `--`, `foo---bar`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern does only describe two characters where the first can be omitted.

I think you want this:

```
/^[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*$/i
```